# Facebook Open Graph Action Appearing on Timeline as Individual Stories Instead of in Aggregate Report

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-opengraph, facebook-timeline

One of my Facebook Open Graph actions is posting individual stories on my timeline for each instance where I post the action, rather than displaying them as an aggregation report. This has resulted in my timeline being completely overrun with stories from this action.  My other action from the same app is not doing this and is properly displaying them in an aggregation report. Why would this action be posting individual stories and how can I disable this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook has acknowledged this as a bug and it is currently assigned a priority of 'Wishlist'.  You can check the status of the bug (and confirm it as reproducible) here: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/378927952140252?browse=search_4f8df5d05c92b3384707485.